# Директивы препроцессора для заголовочных файлов

Tags: препроцессор, директива, c++

для того чтобы подключенный заголовок не включался в код дважды, я использую такую препроцессорную инструкцию

```
#ifndef <имя>
#define <имя>

// контент

#endif
```

в msvs есть аналогичный вариант одной инструкции препроцессора

```
#pragma once
```

вопрос: какому способу отдать предпочтение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тому, который поддерживает Ваш компилятор. Первый способ работает гарантировано  на всех компиляторах.  Некоторые люди практикуют комбинацию этих способов.

Когда-то видел тесты, какой способ дает более быструю компиляцию. Результат - на новых компиляторах разницы практически нет. gcc умеет хорошо оптимизировать такую конструкцию.

Comment: значит все таки первый эффективный из за своей универсальности?

Comment: он просто гарантировано работает.

Comment: Хм, "разницы практически нет" - значит, она есть. Интересно, о какой разнице идет речь?

Comment: Почитал [доку](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC8) на gcc. Там сказано, что ещё 2.9 (а это очень древний компилятор) умел оптимизировать. А pragma once - уже тогда была "не рекомендована к использованию" (`#pragma once' is now obsolete and should not be used at all.)

Да, некоторые компиляторы поддерживают pragma once, но в некоторых случаях (например при помощи ссылок на файл), можно обмануть препроцессор.

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma once` теоретически должна работать быстрее, так как располагается сразу же в начале файла, прочитав эту директиву компилятор остановит обработку. В случае с `#ifndef` компилятор пройдёт до `#endif`, т.е. распарсит весь файл.

Тестов не видел, но думаю на больших проектах в несколько сот тысяч / миллионов строк разница будет заметна (мы у тебя используем `#pragma once`, но у нас всё под одну платформу). Для класса программ "Hello World" заметной разницы не будет.

Минус - `#pragma once` де-юро не поддерживается стандартом, хотя де-факто современные компиляторы про неё знают.

Comment: Быстрее скорее всего потому, что для файла запоминается pragma onсe и при следующем упоминании этого инклуда в этой единице трансляции, препроцессор его пропустит (т.е. не будет ни открытия файла, ни парсинга до прагмы).